# Подскажите как лучше добавлять новые элементы в БД

Tags: javascript, mongodb

вопрос такой. У меня изначально была такая запись в БД:

```
{
  "enterprise": "11",
  "value": [],
}
```

По изначальной задумке предполагалось добавлять новые объекты (в объекте 46 значений) в массив value, но проект очень сильно разросся и теперь приходится в этом массив заливать очень большие объемы, более 2000 новых объектов на одну такую запись. В связи с этим монго ругается:

```
MongoServerError: BSONObj size: 16958811 (0x102C55B) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB)
```

И таких документов будет большое количество.

Какой у меня лучший вариант? Создать новую коллекцию для этих записей?

Comment: если ваша запись именно такова тогда в ней нет воообще никакого смысла. создайте коллекцию из значений хранящихся в value и добавьте в каждую запись поле enterprise

Comment: Там ещё в будущем будут новые поля в виде строк, но не так много